# Which is efficient? SQL Level or Power BI Level

Tags: powerbi

Is append/merge at PowerBI Level more efficient or at the SQL Level?

Should create a view and merge them at SQL level or at the PowerBI Level is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work.

It really depends on your data, and what you need to do with it inside of Power BI thereafter, as Query Folding in Power Query will play a big factor in performance.  Power BI will try and combine your data actions into a single statement for performance, and if it can not create a single query based on your actions, efficiency will be lost.  Actions such as Merging/Appending queries based on different sources, or complex transformation logic will prevent Query Folding - have a read of [Power Query query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding)

Without knowing your data, and Power Query actions, its hard to say, but generally the closer to source you perform your query, the better the performance is likely to be.  The trade off is that your logic may become fragmented across multiple products and the gains in performance may not be worth cost from a maintenance perspective.

Certainly, if you are bringing data in from multiple sources, filtering the data within Power Query and query folding is not possible, you will notice a performance hit, as Power Query will be pulling complete tables, rather than the subset it needs.

You might find it useful to understand what is happening in Power BI during the query loading for your scenario - to do this take a look at [Query Diagnostic Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/querydiagnostics)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option, it is always better to append/merge the data at the SQL level.